# How to right-align text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment

I'm looking to format some text in the same way as showed in the image (highlighted part) where the text is right-aligned and the next line starts in the same horizontal position as the previous one. I tried to use `\hspace` but didn't work as expected.

[image: Example of some text in the wanted format]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SX!

You can achieve that by using a `\parbox` or a `minipage` environment. Use `\hfill` before it, in order to achieve your alignment. I used an `\fbox` additionally in my MWE to have a frame around the text. The `%` can be deleted if you want the marked text to move to the next line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Some text
%
\hfill
\fbox{\parbox[t]{2cm}{This is the text in your marked box.}}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE result]

**edit:** In case you have a small box width and long words, you might get big white spaces. To get the usual typesetting behavior inside a `\parbox`, one could use `\fussy` in the beginning of a `\parbox`. This is the default options latex uses for line breaking. Note, however, this doesn't help with too small boxes, which is the main issue here. You'll get `underfull \hbox` or `overfull \hbox` warnings, but you'll get em until you tackled the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for the text without the border but I already found a way to remove it using \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}.

Comment: @ThulioGuilherme you can easily remove the` \fbox` (and the related `{}`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer stated above, a `\parbox` or a `\minipage`environment does the trick. However, be aware that using \parbox may sometimes lead to undesirable big gaps in the text.
Typeset the following for instance so you can see the problem I am trying to address:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \parbox{3cm}{TUG is an acronym. It means \TeX\ Users Group.}
    \end{document}
```

[image: undesirable_space]

You can avoid it by typing the following command in the preamble, i.e before `\begin{document}`:

```
    \usepackage{microtype}
```

Comment: This feels more like a comment rather than an answer to me. `microtype` only helps in micro-typesetting, hence the name. It will adjust the width of the letters and/or spaces if that can help reduce the badness. To get the usual behavior, one could use `\fussy` in the beginning of a `\parbox`. This is the default options latex uses for line breaking. Note, however, this doesn't help with too small boxes, which is the main issue here. You'll get `underfull \hbox` or `overfull \hbox` warnings, but you'll get em until you tackled the problem.